# Lost credentials to a Linux VM

Tags: linux, boot, root, system-recovery

An employee, who left on bad terms, setup a linux server that we need access to but we can't login.

It is setup on a hyper-v VM.

When booted up it quickly loads the essential drivers then begins the bootup which is visible if you press the `ESC` key.

I will be honest and say I know nothing about linux, but once i get in I'm going to learn. I have tried googling and most everything seems to say to get into the Grub boot menu by either pressing `ESC` or holding `Left Shift` which is not working in my case.

Would really appreciate some help and will provide additional info if it is needed.

Comment: You are a company and you use Linux based VM's, and yet you yourself have no idea about Linux. Seems to me you either need one more employee or at least some freelance IT support. There are way too many variables in your situation, so unless someone here wants to spend hours on helping you (for free), you won't get anywhere.

Comment: If you insist on doing it yourself and really digging into that stuff, here is what you need to do and therefore look for on Google: You need to boot up another Linux VM, then find a way to mount the other (VM) image into it. If you're lucky and there is just a single, not encrypted partition, this will give you access to the configuration files under /etc. You could now delete the password for root and then boot into it without a password. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know It will be a pain I guess.

We use windows server 2012 primarily. We just setup a single Linux server to install Alienvault